# Building JAR at runtime and use it as a referenced library

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runtime, .class-file

I'm building at runtime a JAR which include some file ".class" generated at runtime too. So, to be able to use these ".class" I've added the JAR as a referenced library to the project.
But when I try to use these classe I get the following error:

```
The type com.Crilin cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

What am I missing?